# issues with jquery hover effect using SlipHover

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

i am trying to implement this in a project here [a link](http://colors.textilemarketresearch.com)!, when we hover over products on home page, some times the result is as expected i.e. along with icon and name of product overlay on entire product (as in image1 ) but sometimes its only on certain portion or on inner image only (as in image2)
i am not sure if it is bug or i am making some mistake here. can you please help or suggest a workaround.

image:
  image_1[a link](http://colors.textilemarketresearch.com/image/data/image1.png)!

Comment: how about you expose the code you use for this effect? Including pictures layout.

Comment: hii, @IgorSavinkin actually there is lot of code including css, javascript and actual html and due to my limited score here, i am not able to attach more links or images here, i am using a javascript library SlipHover, [link](https://github.com/wayou/SlipHover/)

Comment: the actual code is present here, [click here link](http://colors.textilemarketresearch.com/)